# Error: Batch entry error in Kafka target database (Null value in the primary key conflict)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, database-replication

**Error:  Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "person" ("ID","NAME") VALUES (NULL,'Alex') ON CONFLICT ("ID") DO UPDATE SET "NAME"=EXCLUDED."NAME" was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.**

**Source** : Oracle Database

**Target**: Postgres

Replication of data using Kafka.

***ISSUE*: Sink connector is inserting *NULL value of ID* in the target database resulting into conflict.**

**Source connector:**

```
{
    "name": "source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.91.138:1521/orcl1",
        "connection.user": "sys as sysdba",
        "connection.password": "oracle",
        "topic.prefix": "person",
        "mode": "incrementing",
        "pk.fields": "ID",
        "poll.interval.ms": "1000",
        "incrementing.column.name":"ID",
        "query": "SELECT * from person",
        "numeric.mapping":"none",
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
        "validate.non.null": "false",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081"
    }

}
```

**Sink connector:**

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics":"person",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.91.229:5432/postgres?user=postgres&password=postgres ",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "pk.fields": "ID",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081"
    }
    }
```

Comment: what kind of update make the ID null?  I think this is something related to your db and actions carried out on it, not the connector itself

Comment: I am just pushing the data using sink connector which is consumed from the source into the target.
The data in the source DB looks like:
ID:1 Name: Alex
However, it is pushing a NULL ID in the target resulting into conflict error.

Comment: does the source data have a field called `ID`, it could be a naming or mapping issue, you can just validate the data being sent by using a simple console consumer to check the data structure and content

Comment: Yes the source data contains field ID. 
I validated the data which is being sent by the consumer using ksql.

ksql> print person from beginning;
Key format: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - no data processed
Value format: AVRO or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2023/02/28 14:28:45.873 Z, key: <null>, value: {"ID": "\u0001", "NAME": "Alex"}, partition: 0

Comment: mmm, is the ID auto-increment column in the source table?, try to check the below configs with the source connector configs `validate.non.null` and `incrementing.column.name` https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html#connector

Comment: another note, update the question title to be more describing the problem instead of having the very verbose error.

Comment: Nope, the ID is not auto-increment. It is inserted manually just like other columns.
Apart from that, I have validated rest of the two configs mentioned by you.